# How can i count words frenquency and append results every time i run the script in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
["one", "two", "three", "three"]
```

I want to open a file and write

```
{"one" => 1, "two" => 1, "three" => 2}



["one", "two"]
```

and in the next time open the same file and search for the each word if exsit append + 1 else create new word

```
{"one" => 2, "two" => 2, "three" => 2}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, i just unchecked the answer, it was so helpful but maybe other answers will help other people :))

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]" along with "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)". Show us the absolute minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having with your code. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions, how to count the frequency, and how to persist data. The first is easy, the second is determined by your needs which you didn't tell us. How big is the list of words? How often do you need to update the list and how fast does it need to run? A database even a simple one like SQLite, can easily do this and would be very fast, even when the list is huge. DBMs are optimized for this sort of query.

Comment: Hey @theTinMan i will check How to ask the next time, and the problem for me was how  how to persist data , this list of words will be used as a training data for an AI so the list of words will be bigger with time , so what do you think is the fastest way i should store and retrieve data from , Json or SQLite ?

Comment: Fastest for what? How much data do you want to store in total? How much data do you want to store per second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year? What are your throughput requirements? What are your latency requirements? What are your jitter requirements? How do you want to access that data? What is the write frequency? Read frequency? Do you need to search it? By which criteria? What is your search frequency? What are your consistency requirements? What are your atomicity requirements? What are your availability requirements? What are your durability requirements? Those are just a tiny …

Comment: … fractions of the questions you need to ask yourself before you can even begin to look for a persistence solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should do :

```
hash = ["one", "two", "three", "three"]

frequency_file = 'frequency.dat'

if File.exists?(frequency_file) 
  old_frequency = File.open(frequency_file) {|f| Marshal.load(f.read)}
else
  old_frequency = {}
end

old_frequency.default = 0


frequency = hash.group_by{|name| name}.map{|name, list| [name,list.count+old_frequency[name]]}.to_h

File.open(frequency_file,'w'){|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(frequency))}

puts frequency.inspect
# => {"one"=>1, "two"=>1, "three"=>2}
# => {"one"=>2, "two"=>2, "three"=>4}
```

If you prefer a human-readable file :

```
require 'yaml'
hash = ["one", "two", "three", "three"]

frequency_file = 'frequency.yml'

if File.exists?(frequency_file) 
  old_frequency = YAML.load_file(frequency_file)
else
  old_frequency = {}
end

old_frequency.default = 0


frequency = hash.group_by{|name| name}.map{|name, list| [name,list.count+old_frequency[name]]}.to_h

File.open(frequency_file,'w'){|f| f.write frequency.to_yaml}

puts frequency.inspect
# => {"one"=>1, "two"=>1, "three"=>2}
# => {"one"=>2, "two"=>2, "three"=>4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some variations that'd do it:

```
ary = %w[a b a c a b]

ary.group_by { |v| v }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_h # => {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
ary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |v, h| h[v] += 1} # => {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
ary.uniq.map { |v| [v, ary.count(v)] }.to_h # => {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
```

Since they're all about the same length it becomes important to know which is the fastest.

```
require 'fruity'

ary = %w[a b a c a b] * 1000

compare do
  group_by { ary.group_by { |v| v }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_h }
  each_with_object { ary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |v, h| h[v] += 1} }
  uniq_map { ary.uniq.map { |v| [v, ary.count(v)] }.to_h }
end

# >> Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> group_by is faster than uniq_map by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
# >> uniq_map is faster than each_with_object by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
```

How to persist the data and append to it is a separate question and how to do it depends on the size of the data you're checking, and how fast you need the code to run. Databases are very capable of doing these sort of checks extremely fast as they have code optimized to search and count unique occurrences of records. Even SQLite should have no problem doing this. Using an ORM like Sequel or ActiveRecord would make it painless to talk to the DB and to scale or port to a more capable database manager if needed.

Writing to a local file is OK if you occasionally need to update, or you don't have a big list of words, and you don't need to share the information with other pieces of code or with another machine.

Reading a file to recover the hash then incrementing it assumes a word will never be deleted, they'll only be added. I've written a lot of document analysis code and that case hasn't occurred, so I'd recommend thinking about long-term use before settling on your particular path.

Comment: The case here is Mining tweets and after cleaning the data i'll put each set of keywords in a separate file based on a category , so i wanna count the frequency of them and add it as long as i keep mining . after that i'll will compare another array X to the same files to extract the keywords of the array X

i'm still in learning curve so what do you suggest would work for me in this case a SQLite , Json or Yaml files ?

Answer (score -1):

Could you put the string representation of a hash (the first line of the file) in a separate (e.g., JSON) file? If so, consider something like the following.

First let's create a JSON file for the hash and a second file, the words of which are to be counted.

```
require 'json'

FName = "lucy"
JSON_Fname = "hash_counter.json"

File.write(JSON_Fname, JSON.generate({"one" => 1, "two" => 1, "three" => 2}))
  #=> 27

File.write(FName, '["one", "two", "three", "three"]')
  #=>32
```

First read the JSON file, parse the hash and give `h` a default value of zero.<sup>1</sup>.

```
h = JSON.parse(File.read(JSON_Fname))
  #=> {"one"=>1, "two"=>1, "three"=>2}

h.default = 0
```

(See [Hash#default=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D)). Then read the other file and update the hash.

```
File.read(FName).downcase.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/).each { |w| h[w] += 1 }
  h #=> {"one"=>2, "two"=>2, "three"=>4}
```

Lastly, write the hash `h` to the JSON file (as I did above).<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1 Ruby expands `h[w] += 1` to `h[w] = h[w] + 1` before parsing the expression. If `h` does not have a key `w`, [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns the hash's default value, if it has one. Here `h["cat"] #=> 0` since `h` has no key `"cat"` and the default has been set to zero. The expression therefore becomes `h[w] = 0 + 1 #=> 1`. Note that the method on the left of the equality is [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), which is why the default value does not apply there.</sup>

<sup>2 To be safe, write the new JSON string to a temporary file, delete the JSON file, then rename the temporary file to the former JSON file name.</sup>